# Do I need dnsmasq?

Tags: network-manager, dnsmasq

When I nmap localhost get this:

```
53/tcp open domain dnsmasq 2.59
```

What is it and do I really need it?
I tried to remove it with

```
sudo apt-get remove dnsmasq-base
```

but it said if I would continue it will remove `network-manager` and `network-manager-gnome` too.
So do I need it for `network-manager` and `network-manager-gnome` or if I don't can I just remove it because I don't want to have it listen on *port 53*.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand , dnsmasq is some configurable DHCP server .

From [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq)

DNSmasq provides two services, either of which can be used independently.

1. DNS service
2. DHCP service (including features relating to network boot)

A local DNS cache can speed up internet browsing because the user's browser will not need to access a domain name server when it looks up a domain name the computer has visited before.

From Ubuntu The main point :**Note that the package "dnsmasq" interferes with Network Manager which can use "dnsmasq-base" to provide DHCP services when sharing an internet connection.**

Other Sources:

**Dnsmasq** is a lightweight, easy to configure DNS forwarder and DHCP server. It is designed to provide DNS and, optionally, DHCP, to a small network. It can serve the names of local machines which are not in the global DNS. The DHCP server integrates with the DNS server and allows machines with DHCP-allocated addresses to appear in the DNS with names configured either in each host or in a central configuration file. Dnsmasq supports static and dynamic DHCP leases and BOOTP/TFTP/PXE for network booting of diskless machines.

Source:[www.thekelleys.org.uk](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html)

Comment: So do I need it?

Comment: well if you have a DHCP server then you probably need it .

Comment: @user113527 bold line can answer you .

Comment: But for what is it opening a port?

Comment: that indicates from which port the connection shared .